# Create custom executable name in setup file

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I would like to have in my InnoSetup possibility to allow customer to install one of two programs or to install both.

I made additional choose panel where user check what he wants to install but I have following questions

1. How to change hardcoded AppName?
2. How to dynamically tell where to install program?

   For e.g. default installation dir is > `Program Files\Program 1`
   how to change that to `Program Files\Program 2`
3. How to change UninstallDisplayIcon?

   Currently `UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\program1.exe`

   How to change it depends of chose settings to: `UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\program2.exe`

---

Current configuration (from comment):

```
[Run]
Filename: {app}\{#MyAppExeName};
Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,{#MyAppName}};
Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Where MyAppExeName is currently constant defined at the beginning of the file.

My question is how to do something like this:

```
[Run]
Filename: {app}\MYFUNCTIONFROMCODESECTION_THAT_WILL_RETURN_NAME;
Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,{#MyAppName}};
Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: 1. That makes little sense to me. Hardcoded `AppName` ? What do you mean by that ? 2. Dynamically tell where to install the files you can e.g. with `{code:}` scripted constant. 3. That you can do (I hope) also with `{code:}` scripted constant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer TLama, but please be kind and give short example cause I didn't find out how to do that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I could, but I don't know what you're going to do :) Are you just asking how to define conditionally all the things you listed by a certain condition (in your case the selected programs) ?

Comment: Please check this:
[Run]
Filename: {app}\{#MyAppExeName}; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,{#MyAppName}}; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

Where MyAppExeName is currently constant defined at the beginning of the file. My question is how to do something like this >
[Run]
Filename: {app}\MYFUNCTIONFROMCODESECTION_THAT_WILL_RETURN_NAME; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,{#MyAppName}}; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

Comment: Sorry for no reply, but you need to add `@` char before the user's name in comment so the person will be notified (like e.g. `@TLama`). We don't have to, because you're the owner of the post and thus you're always notified about new comments. To your comment question (I think point 2.), you can do it [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/xvJbHEup). But the rest of the question is still quite unclear to me. 1. The `AppName` you cannot set during the runtime because it's evaluated at the setup initialization if that is what you asked. 3. [`This way`](http://pastebin.com/TMBHRzD2).

Comment: @TLama - your answer helped me partially but for the rest I found some code on the net. Very trivial, for installation path I had to change DirText label during that step etc. I've solved Uninstall as well.
Your tip helped me a lot so please make answer so that I can give you points. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to post an answer (tomorrow, since I don't have enough time now and there is still 23 hours bounty grace period) for what I think you've asked. Sorry, I wasn't sure about the questions to give you precise answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***How to change the AppName directive value at runtime ?***

It is not possible to change the [`AppName`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appname) directive value at runtime since it is evaluated at the installer's initialization time.

***How to conditionally specify the installed file destination ?***

For this you can use the [`{code:...}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) scripted constant. For instance:

```
[Files]
Source: "MyApp.exe"; DestDir: "{code:GetMyAppDestDir}"

[Code]
function GetMyAppDestDir(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := '<Here return the path where the file should be installed...>';
end;
```

***How to change the UninstallDisplayIcon directive value at runtime ?***

For this you can also use the [`{code:...}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) scripted constant. For instance:

```
[Setup]
UninstallDisplayIcon={code:GetUninstallDisplayIcon}

[Code]
function GetUninstallDisplayIcon(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := '<Here return the path of the icon to be used for uninstaller...>';
end;
```